# How to wait Retrofit2 response handling properly with Coroutine?

Tags: android, retrofit, coroutine

I would like to write a code that puts a token in the header for api call. When the token is expired after some minutes, requesting token process is invoked and after the process is getting completed, the api call should be called again with refreshed token.

for that, I am using `Coroutine` and `suspend fun` for Retrofit `Response`.

However, when a token is needed, the api is called again without waiting for the token-requesting api and its callback to finish.

How can I properly await for both executions of getting `Response` from api call and handling it in the main thread?

Below is the code I wrote.

#### ApiViewModel

```kotlin
fun <T> apiCall(
    api: suspend () -> Response<RecvBase<T>>,
    callback: ((T) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = api()
        result.body()?.let { recv -> 
            if (recv.isTokenRefreshingRequired) {
                val tokenProcess = async { requestNewToken() }
                tokenProcess.await()
                apiCall(api, callback)
                return@launch
            }
            // handle with callback
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun requestAccessToken() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = service.requestNewToken()
        result.body()?.data?.let {
            token = it
        }
    }
}
```

#### ApiService

```kotlin
interface ApiService {
    @POST("/newToken")
    suspend fun requestNewToken(...): Response<RecvBase<String>>
}
```

I used `async` - `await`, `launch` - `join`, but neither of them had worked. I assume that the code waits for execution just until requesting token api is called, then not waiting for its callback invoked.